# Why there is sometimes a delay for samba connection?

Tags: delay, samba

I have samba 4.15.13 installed on an Ubuntu 22.04 server for a shared disk with 40 clients (all of them are windows machines).
When a client tries to open a folder (or open/save a file) on shared disk, **sometimes** there is a significant delay until the job done. For example, if they try to open a folder, a green bar may be loading for sometime on top of file explorer. Or if they try to save a file, a window with a message (communication with smb:\\share\path_to_file) is shown up for a while. This delay could be 2-3 seconds to 15-20 seconds, so it is a real inconvenience.
A user claims that this problem is usually appeared when enough time has passed from the previous connection to smb shared from their machine - I can not be sure for this.
Is there any relative setting on samba server? Any other idea on how to solve this?